# Squid Proxy error for ftps

Tags: squid, ftps

I'm running Squid v3.5.15 (installed on Windows Server 2012R2) as a simple relay to other external servers. Using Total Commander to connect, everything works for ftp, but fails for ftps. What have I missed? The access log reads:

```
1480977720.502      1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TAG_NONE/400 3911 GET ftps://username:password@somewhere.com/ - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/squid-ftps-td1032491.html that doesn't seem to be supported.